# Error Message when using ChartJS with React

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

"Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports."

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
var CanvasJSReact = require('./canvasjs.react');
var CanvasJSChart = CanvasJSReact.CanvasJSChart;

export class Chart1 extends Component {
    render() {
    const options = {
      title: {
        text: "Basic Column Chart in React"
      },
      data: [{              
                type: "column",
                dataPoints: [
                    { label: "Apple",  y: 10  },
                    { label: "Orange", y: 15  },
                    { label: "Banana", y: 25  },
                    { label: "Mango",  y: 30  },
                    { label: "Grape",  y: 28  }
                ]
       }]
   }

   return (
      <div>
        <CanvasJSChart options = {options}
            /* onRef = {ref => this.chart = ref} */
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You should include your code with the question, not just paste an image of it.

Comment: my apologies. thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Try `export default class Chart1 extends Component {`